# zf2 phpunit controller dependency

Tags: unit-testing, dependency-injection, phpunit, zend-framework2

I'm unit testing my controller called `IndexController` (used the http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/user-guide/modules.html tutorial).

My IndexController has a dependency:`Translator $translator`.

```
<?php
// module/Application/src/Application/Controller/IndexController.php

namespace Application\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Zend\I18n\Translator\Translator;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
    protected $translator;

    public function __construct(Translator $translator)
    {
        $this->translator = $translator;
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {                
        $steeringWheelMapper = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('SupplierName\Mapper\SteeringWheel');
        $carBrandList = $steeringWheelMapper ->fetchCarBrandList();
        return new ViewModel();
    }
}
```

My unit test setup:

- module

  - Application

    - test

      - ApplicationTest

        - Controller

          - IndexControllerTest.php
      - Bootstrap.php
      - phpunit.xml.dist
      - TestConfig.php.dist

Testing now gives the following error:
`Argument 1 passed to Application\Controller\IndexController::__construct() must be an instance of Zend\I18n\Translator\Translator, none given`.
Nothing strange here, but I can't find out where to add the translator object..

Where should I add the translator object?

The code

```
<?php
// module/Application/test/Testconfig.php.dist
return array(
    'modules' => array(
        'Application',
    ),
    'module_listener_options' => array(
        'config_glob_paths'    => array(
            '../../../config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php',
        ),
        'module_paths' => array(
            'module',
            'vendor',
        ),
    ),
);

<?php
// module/Application/test/Bootstrap.php

namespace ApplicationTest;//Change this namespace for your test

use Zend\Loader\AutoloaderFactory;
use Zend\Mvc\Service\ServiceManagerConfig;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager;
use Zend\Stdlib\ArrayUtils;
use RuntimeException;

error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
chdir(__DIR__);

class Bootstrap
{
    protected static $serviceManager;
    protected static $config;
    protected static $bootstrap;

    public static function init()
    {
        // Load the user-defined test configuration file, if it exists; otherwise, load
        if (is_readable(__DIR__ . '/TestConfig.php')) {
            $testConfig = include __DIR__ . '/TestConfig.php';
        } else {
            $testConfig = include __DIR__ . '/TestConfig.php.dist';
        }

        $zf2ModulePaths = array();

        if (isset($testConfig['module_listener_options']['module_paths'])) {
            $modulePaths = $testConfig['module_listener_options']['module_paths'];
            foreach ($modulePaths as $modulePath) {
                if (($path = static::findParentPath($modulePath)) ) {
                    $zf2ModulePaths[] = $path;
                }
            }
        }

        $zf2ModulePaths  = implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, $zf2ModulePaths) . PATH_SEPARATOR;
        $zf2ModulePaths .= getenv('ZF2_MODULES_TEST_PATHS') ?: (defined('ZF2_MODULES_TEST_PATHS') ? ZF2_MODULES_TEST_PATHS : '');

        static::initAutoloader();

        // use ModuleManager to load this module and it's dependencies
        $baseConfig = array(
            'module_listener_options' => array(
                'module_paths' => explode(PATH_SEPARATOR, $zf2ModulePaths),
            ),
        );

        $config = ArrayUtils::merge($baseConfig, $testConfig);

        $serviceManager = new ServiceManager(new ServiceManagerConfig());
        $serviceManager->setService('ApplicationConfig', $config);
        $serviceManager->get('ModuleManager')->loadModules();

        static::$serviceManager = $serviceManager;
        static::$config = $config;
    }

    public static function getServiceManager()
    {
        return static::$serviceManager;
    }

    public static function getConfig()
    {
        return static::$config;
    }

    protected static function initAutoloader()
    {
        $vendorPath = static::findParentPath('vendor');

        if (is_readable($vendorPath . '/autoload.php')) {
            $loader = include $vendorPath . '/autoload.php';
        } else {
            $zf2Path = getenv('ZF2_PATH') ?: (defined('ZF2_PATH') ? ZF2_PATH : (is_dir($vendorPath . '/ZF2/library') ? $vendorPath . '/ZF2/library' : false));

            if (!$zf2Path) {
                throw new RuntimeException('Unable to load ZF2. Run `php composer.phar install` or define a ZF2_PATH environment variable.');
            }

            include $zf2Path . '/Zend/Loader/AutoloaderFactory.php';

        }

        AutoloaderFactory::factory(array(
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'autoregister_zf' => true,
                'namespaces' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                ),
            ),
        ));
    }

    protected static function findParentPath($path)
    {
        $dir = __DIR__;
        $previousDir = '.';
        while (!is_dir($dir . '/' . $path)) {
            $dir = dirname($dir);
            if ($previousDir === $dir) return false;
            $previousDir = $dir;
        }
        return $dir . '/' . $path;
    }
}

Bootstrap::init();

<?php
// module/Application/test/ApplicationTest/Controller/IndexControllerTest.php

namespace ApplicationTest\Controller;

use ApplicationTest\Bootstrap;
use Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\TreeRouteStack as HttpRouter;
use Application\Controller\IndexController;
use Zend\Http\Request;
use Zend\Http\Response;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;
use Zend\Mvc\Router\RouteMatch;
use PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase;

class IndexControllerTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    protected $controller;
    protected $request;
    protected $response;
    protected $routeMatch;
    protected $event;

    protected function setUp()
    {
        $serviceManager = Bootstrap::getServiceManager();
        $this->controller = new IndexController();
        $this->request    = new Request();
        $this->routeMatch = new RouteMatch(array('controller' => 'index'));
        $this->event      = new MvcEvent();
        $config = $serviceManager->get('Config');
        $routerConfig = isset($config['router']) ? $config['router'] : array();
        $router = HttpRouter::factory($routerConfig);

        $this->event->setRouter($router);
        $this->event->setRouteMatch($this->routeMatch);
        $this->controller->setEvent($this->event);
        $this->controller->setServiceLocator($serviceManager);
    }

    public function testIndexActionCanBeAccessed()
    {
        $this->routeMatch->setParam('action', 'index');

        $result   = $this->controller->dispatch($this->request);
        $response = $this->controller->getResponse();

        $this->assertEquals(200, $response->getStatusCode());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject it in your setUp method

```
protected function setUp()
{
    // ...
    $translator = new \Zend\I18n\Translator;
    $this->controller = new IndexController($translator);
    // ....
}
```